# Alamofire project where I get response in my current function but not in another parent class

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm working on an iOS weather app with Alamofire API module. I wrote code for getting information from the net for the weather update and I am getting it when I print it just after getting information but I cannot get that information to show in my view controller.

Here is the code.

```
public var cityName:String{
    if _cityName==nil{
        _cityName = "Didn't find any"
    }
    return _cityName
}

public var weatherType:String{
    if _weatherType==nil{
        _weatherType="oops"
    }
    return _weatherType
}

public var currentTemp: Double{
    if _currentTemp==nil{
        _currentTemp=0.0
    }
    return _currentTemp
}

public var date: String{
    if _date==nil{
        _date=""

    }
    let dateFormatter=DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
    let currentDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    self._date = "Today, \(currentDate)"
    return _date
}

func downloadWeatherDetails(completed: DownloadComplete){
    let currentWeatherURL = URL(string: CURRENT_WEATHER_URL)!
    Alamofire.request(currentWeatherURL).responseJSON{
        response in
        let result = response.result

        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
            if let name = dict["name"]as? String{
                 self._cityName=name.capitalized
                    print(self._cityName)
            }
            if let weather = dict["weather"]as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]{
                if let main = weather[0]["main"] as? String{
                    self._weatherType=main.capitalized
                    print(self._weatherType)
                }
            }
            if let main = dict["main"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                if let currentTemp = main["temp"] as? Double{
                    let kelvintoCelcius = (currentTemp - 273.15)

                    self._currentTemp=kelvintoCelcius
                    print(self._currentTemp)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    completed()
}
```

Comment: You are not setting any label text. How do you want the View Controller to show it if you dont tell him to?

Comment: The request is async. Why do you call `complete()` no in the Alamofire closure?

Comment: @JuanCurti How do I set any label text ?

Comment: @RaunakTrikha "cannot get that information to show in my view controller". Where do you exactly want the information to be shown?

Comment: @JuanCurti maybe I can send you my Xcode project file ? That'll be helpful.

Comment: @RaunakTrikha Sure!

Comment: @JuanCurti whats your email id ?

Comment: @RaunakTrikha Just upload it to drive or something like that and paste the link here

Comment: @JuanCurti https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzWwjHdOZO2LTUpReUw5aTNpTU0   Thank you

Comment: @RaunakTrikha I couldn't see the storyboard (It was corrupt or something), but as I could see, you are setting the labels content in the right way. Check if in your viewController your weather is updated after the completion handler in downloadWeatherDetails.

Comment: @JuanCurti      I get the weather response when I print it immediately just after I declare Dictionary but not when I try to print it after completed().

Comment: @RaunakTrikha I will add a possible fix as an answer. Give me a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this function in your ViewController.swift:

```
func downloadWeatherDetails(callback: @escaping (CurrentWeather)->Void){
        var currentWeather = CurrentWeather()
        let currentWeatherURL = URL(string: CURRENT_WEATHER_URL)!
        Alamofire.request(currentWeatherURL).responseJSON{
            response in
            let result = response.result

            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                if let name = dict["name"]as? String{
                    currentWeather._cityName=name.capitalized
                    print(currentWeather._cityName)
                }
                if let weather = dict["weather"]as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]{
                    if let main = weather[0]["main"] as? String{
                        currentWeather._weatherType=main.capitalized
                        print(currentWeather._weatherType)
                    }
                }
                if let main = dict["main"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                    if let currentTemp = main["temp"] as? Double{
                        let kelvintoCelcius = (currentTemp - 273.15)

                        currentWeather._currentTemp=kelvintoCelcius
                        print(currentWeather._currentTemp)
                    }
                callback(currentWeather)
            }
        }
    }
```

Replace your viewDidLoad with:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.downloadWeatherDetails {
            newWeather in
            currentWeather = newWeather
            self.updateMainUI()
        }
    }
```

Comment: THANK YOU very much, that helped. :) It's showing the updates on the VC now.

Comment: @RaunakTrikha Glad it helped you! Please mark my answer as correct if this worked for you

Comment: and how do I convert the temperature which is coming in Double into an integer value ?

Comment: Int(YourVariable).

Comment: can't figure out where to convert the Double into Int.

Comment: currentTemp.text= "\(Int(currentWeather.currentTemp))"

Comment: its printing the string literal.

Comment: Sorry, I forget a slash: currentTemp.text= "\(Int(currentWeather.currentTemp))"

Comment: I am getting an error saying "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when I find the city name using Dictionary for my current location, here is the link of the view controller. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzWwjHdOZO2LOUZQWWpETDhPc0k

Comment: In that ase, @RaunakTrikha, you have to ask another question. We cant debug the whole application commenting here lol. Ask another question, in the meantime I will be reviewing that issue